# Insert code in .php file with file_put_contents

Tags: php, smarty

Let's say I have a .php file and I want to insert a new line of code without changing the original file.

Example:

```
require_once 'includes/application_top.php';
$smarty = new Smarty;
require  DIR_FS_CATALOG . 'templates/' . CURRENT_TEMPLATE . '/source/boxes.php';
include  DIR_WS_MODULES . 'default.php';
require  DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'header.php';
$smarty->assign('language', $_SESSION['language']);
```

Between line 3 and 4 I would like to insert any code with `file_put_contents`.
Is it possible to read the file by `file_get_contents` and insert any code?

Comment: Try an include() statement.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you use `file_put_contents` it will modify the original file.

Comment: I bet there is a better way to accomplish what you want. Could you use conditional logic or something?

Comment: Which file do you want to write to with `file_put_contents()`?

Comment: Yeah, this really sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Answering your question - yes, it is possible. But what do you want to achieve?

Comment: In other files there is an auto_include point like foreach(auto_include(DIR_FS_CATALOG.'includes/extra/configure/','php') as $file) require_once ($file); but it is inconsistent and for this file I need it for it is missing this auto_include.

Comment: Are you talking about modifying page2.php file on the server in the code of page1.php before navigating from 1 to 2?  That is not very safe, especially for 2+ users.  Are you talking about page 2 modifying itself as it loads?  require_once does exactly that, so use it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you have php code in external file and you want to add new line to its content using another php code, if that is right you can use the following code:

```js
<?php

$content = file_get_content("a.php");

function add_new_line($content, $insert_code, $line_number){
 $lines = explode("\n", $content);
 $segment_1 = array_slice($lines, 0, $line_number);
 $segment_2 = array_slice($lines, $line_number, count($lines) - 1);
 array_push($segment_1, $insert_code);
 $lines = array_merge($segment_1, $segment_2);
 return $str = implode("\n", $lines);
}


$line_number = 3;
$insert_code = "echo 'this is new line';";

// add new line of code to the content
$new_content = add_new_line($content, $insert_code, $line_number);

// insert new file content:
file_put_content("a.php", $new_content);
```

I hope this is useful for you

Comment: This makes sense if it is some kind of job that will be run exactly once on the file.  If this code is run when users access a page instead of by you using a private URL, a.php will have the extra code added over and over again.